# Lens settings missing from camera settings

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, fluid-simulation

The lens settings such as these, specifically the Clip start and end buttons,:

[image: shows lens setti]

Are completely missing from my panel. This is what I see:

[image: Shows my settings with missing lens settings and other things]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT**
I have found where they are located but upon changing them nothing happens to the preview.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPnWK.jpg

Comment: In the image at the bottom you just need to scroll up to find the lens settings, or enlarge the window.

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried any can't scroll and enlarging it does nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in an early pre-release version of Blender 2.80 which was fixed in February 2019.

- https://developer.blender.org/T61499
- https://developer.blender.org/rB5e3838faa2e6dae0ac52860085f5dc4b7a000ea5

You should at least update to the proper release of [Blender 2.80](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/) or, [if your hardware supports it](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/), the current long-term support (LTS) version [Blender 2.83.6](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.83/) or the most recent release [Blender 2.90](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.90/).

[The LTS](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/) is a version of Blender that will continue to receive bug fixes for a span of 2 years after its initial release, while the 2.90 release will be superseded by 2.91 in November 2020.

> The Blender LTS program is aimed at ensuring that long-lasting
> projects can be executed using a stable Blender version, which will
> provide critical fixes throughout a 2-year time span. The LTS version
> will not have any new features, API changes or improvements. Any
> critical fix that is applied to the 2.9 series will be regularly
> ported over to Blender 2.83 LTS.

Comment: how exactly do i update it? Is it like installing a completely new version of blender? Will all my old projects not work? And which one do you recommend

Comment: Blender doesn't auto-update, you have to download a newer version from the website. Multiple versions of Blender can be installed alongside of each other. You can also use the portable version (.zip) if you don't want to install it, just extract it and run. If you want Blender projects to be automatically associated with the newer version, you should use the installer. Old projects should open in newer versions without issues. However, once saved in a newer version they might not open properly in older versions.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: so i want to download the .msi file for the installer?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Now my fluid simulation is gone when I open up the file

Comment: Right, in Blender 2.82 the old fluid and smoke simulation engine was replaced with Mantaflow. If you need the old fluid simulator you will have to use 2.81 or earlier.

Comment: Yeah I got it to work now. I am just using the completed 2.8 link you sent and I had to re-bake it but now its working and I can see the camera settings so ty

Answer (score 0):

The options are there, you just need to scroll up or down to find them, or make the properties window larger.

[image]

Note that you can visualize the  clip distance if you enable viewport display > Show limits.

The line that appears shows clearly the start and end points for the clip distance. Any object that is not within that range will be ignored or clipped.

[image]

Note that the camera clip distance and the clip distance for the viewport are independent.

Comment: I can't scroll down